# How to fix 12V RGB LED Strip connection to NodeMCU?

Tags: led, wires, nodemcu

I am trying to hook 12V RGB Led Strip (LTROP SMD 5050 RGB LED Light Strip) to a NodeMCU unit. I know there are many different tutorials on this and I am very new to wiring and electric circuits.

I used BUZ91A n-MOSFETs and 150 Ohm resistors for each of the RGB channels, and the board is using it's own power supply via usb.

[image: my wiring]

I use very simple code to check if the setup works:

```
#define REDPIN D3
#define GREENPIN D1
#define BLUEPIN D2

#define FADESPEED 5     // make this higher to slow down

void setup() {
  pinMode(REDPIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GREENPIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BLUEPIN, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Finished setup");
}


void loop() {
    analogWrite(REDPIN, 800);
    analogWrite(BLUEPIN, 1020);
    analogWrite(GREENPIN, 400);
    delay(100);

  Serial.println("Finished loop");
}
```

I suspect nothing works because NodeMCU and the LED are using different power sources and the fact they have common ground doesn't seem to be everything required.

Comment: What happens when you try to PWM the built-in LED? BTW, you don't have to execute `analogWrite()` again and again in the loop, it is enough to do that only once in `setup()` but that isn't the problem.

Comment: It works fine with D0 - it changes the brightness based on value in analogWrite()

Comment: The connection is OK. Which NodeMCU board/version do you have? The pin mapping may be different from the Arduino defines. For example my NodeMCU (LoLin) has built-in LED on pin 2 which is D4. D0 is pin 16 so the other pins might differ too on your board.

Comment: Looks like version 1.0 to me. The Arduino IDE "Get Board Info" does not tell much: VID: 10C4, PID: EA60

Comment: I would first try to blink a LED using `digitalWrite()` on D1, D2 and D3 (one by one) to see if these outputs are really associated with the pins where you connected the PWM outputs (just don't forget the current limiting resistor, max source current is 12 mA and max sink current is 20 mA). And you might first try to change the PWM frequency, for example try with `analogWriteFreq(200);`. The default PWM frequency is 1 kHz and that should work but nothing to loose if you try.

Comment: I connected a 3V LEd to D1 (used for G channel in my setup) pin and ground and it stays led all the time. Changing the analogWriteFreq() did not help, but the onboard led changes it's brightness with either.

Comment: If I just try to digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);, the 3V led works fine while the RGB leds on the strip are not reacting

Comment: Did you use PWM to light the LED on D1 or did you toggle the output with some delay to confirm that really is D1 pin? Next I would try to connect a jumper wire from one of the 3.3 V pins on NodeMCU board to the resistor connected to MOSFET's gate to see if that will trigger the transistor and light up the corresponding LED strip channel.

Comment: I am sure it's the right pin. I think it's something about the wiring or maybe the mostef is not the right type or something.

Comment: The MOSFET should be OK, I checked the datasheet. Try to trigger the MOSFET by connecting NodeMCU 3.3 V pin directly to the resistor at the transistor's gate, as I suggested in the last comment. Or try to trigger it with external 3.3 or 5 V. Double check if the strip is connected correctly - remove the MOSFET and use a jumper wire to short the breadboard contacts where source and drain were before you removed the transistor.

Comment: I haven't figured it out but I noticed that sometimes when I unhook the nodeMCU from the ground, the leds on the strip go bright.

Comment: Wow, I think I got it now - when I swap the D0 pin to Vin (5V in my case since I am using USB power), the leds on the strips work. Does it mean that the D* pins aren't giving the MOSTEF enough current?

Comment: No, MOS**FE**T's (not MOS**TE**F, I can see you are **repeating** the same 'typing' mistake) gate current draw is near zero. The problem could be the voltage but I still can't tell because you still didn't try what I suggested already twice :-) To say one more time: There are a few pins on NodeMCU board marked with **3** or with **3V3**. Connect **one of these** pins to the resistor in transistor's gate to see if **3.3 V from NodeMCU** can trigger the transistor. Only then we could know what's going on.

Comment: Nope, the 3v3 does not trigger it - only the 5v does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So now we finally know the reason is **MOSFET's threshold voltage is too high**. The solution is to drive the gate with NPN transistor (you can use BC547 or 2N5551 or similar). You have to connect it's collector to 5 V and it's emitter to GND. Put 10k or 100k resistor between 5 V and the collector, connect the collector to MOSFET's gate and GPIO to the base of NPN transistor. Put some resistor between GPIO and the base of the transistor, maybe 4k7 or similar.

Note:
**HIGH** from GPIO will switch **off** the LED strip and **LOW** will switch it **on**.

Another solution is to use MOSFET with lower threshold voltage.

**EDIT:**
If you want to avoid adding NPN transistor you can use **NTD5867NL** MOSFET which has max threshold voltage 2.5 V so it will for sure work with 3.3 V at the gate but is rather expensive (about $4). Much better solution is adding cheap NPN transistor.

**EDIT:**
Here is the schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgGXyS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**EDIT:**
Here is the correct wiring:
[image]

Comment: Can you please advise on a fitting MOSFET model to use?

Comment: I'll take a look through some other MOSFETs and write you a note if I find the one which might work.

Comment: I've edited the answer and added the data about MOSFET which will for sure work with 3.3 V.

Comment: Thank you so much for following through on this problem with me. I wanted to ask one last question. Are there any sort of Led Strip Driver Boards I could just purchase and wire to my nodeMCU? I suck at all this wiring and circuits (you can tell) and the further I go the better I understand I'd rather stick to the programming side of things. Also, I am trying to finish by project on time for someone's Christmas gift. Again, thanks a lot for your kind help.

Comment: I'm not aware of such driver board. What I've found is only [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/282283688390) and [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/152310172498) RGB LED strip controller, but that is another way of controlling the strip. It has the onboard IC for PWM and you have to send the data using clock&data signals. This is the [IC's datasheet](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeeedDocument/Grove-Chainable_RGB_LED/master/res/P9813_datasheet.pdf). But you really don't have to run from adding just one more transistor, you can do that in a minute. BTW, you may accept the answer if you liked it :-)

Comment: I will try to connect the transistor - haven't figured the wiring yet. Base, collector, all that - have to do some reading first :)

Comment: Here you are the schematic. NPN transistor is just like MOSFET except instead of G, S and D you have B, E and C. Emitter is marked with an arrow and base is where you connect the signal from GPIO. Resistor values are not critical but if the values are to high you might need to lower the PWM frequency.

Comment: I guess I failed to wire these correctly. [I did the wiring](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hempd2b8ntk3b8c/setup%20with%20transistor.png?dl=0) and the led does not work BUT if I unplug the wire from transistor base and grab it with my bare hand, the led will shine :)

Comment: I tried without resistors - didn't work
I tried to check the voltage on the 5V pin - it's 4.6V
I also checked continuity between different wires on the board (just to make sure everything is connected) and it appears so, I am now out of options :)

Comment: I also tried a different power supply for the nodeMCU, this one gives 4.9V and 3A - hasn't helped; I also tried hooking up a different LED strip (regular one color) - hasn't helped either.

Comment: You didn't wire the circuit correctly. You connected the base of NPN transistor directly to the MOSFET's gate (the result is as if there isn't NPN transistor), one resistor is missing and you connected the collector of NPN transistor to 3.3 V instead to 5 V. If that even is the collector. Which NPN transistor did you use?

Comment: Here you are the wiring diagram. You can use the same 12 V which you are using to power the LED strip instead of 5 V to avoid using 3 different voltages. But, as you are probably getting 3.3 V from 5 V then it isn't a problem if you use 5 V. Of course, a MOSFET must be n-channel and not as in the picture.

Comment: BTW, why would you unaccept the correct answer just because you did not wire the circuit according to the schematic I gave you? :-)

Comment: I only unticked it because people normally ignored answered questions and since I hasn't gotten it resolved yet, I wanted to sort of let others tip in seeing an answered question, that's all. It actually works now. Thanks a bunch. I now realize I need to stick with programming and get OTB hardware as much as possible :) Again, many thanks!

Comment: One thing I noticed is that it works in inverted mode - like when I plug it in, without even getting the nodemcu powered up, the leds are led. And then when the nodemcu commands HIGH to the pin, the led turns off. And if I remove the connection between the third leg of 2N5551 and the +12V, it keeps working the same way without any difference. I know I most likely messed up the wiring and I can't stop laughing at how much time I spent with this and all the trouble I cause people with my stupid questions but I just had to share this :)

Comment: You did not mess the wiring this time :-) Take a look at the `note` I wrote in my answer already before I gave you the schematic where I said: '**HIGH** from GPIO will switch **off** the LED strip and **LOW** will switch it **on**'. That is because NPN transistor works as inverter. As for avoiding hardware - do not avoid it!! Being a programmer means you learn fast and your SO reputation confirms you have that ability. So, instead of avoiding - learn it, it's as much fun as programming. I am glad your circuit finally works and hope you'll finish the gift on time, before Christmas! :-)

Comment: On the above circuit mosfet switching will depend on collector current as I have 24v/5A source connected to the drain, for switching I am give 5v on gate